# can Asp.net identity security model used in WCF?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

my manager asking me to port the ASp.net Identity security model to WCF service. is this possible? any ideas to implement token based security in WCF?

Any ideas are welcome.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675663/can-asp-net-identity-security-model-used-in-wcf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910304/how-to-use-asp-net-identity-model-for-wcf-service-authorization-and-authenticati, try searching.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is **Yes**. It's **possible.**

Go and tell your manager, Google have lot of reviews and documents for identity security model used in WCF.

And show him to the below links.

- [WCF: Authentication Service or token-based security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349539/wcf-authentication-service-or-token-based-security)
- [Link 1](http://leastprivilege.com/2011/11/15/token-based-authentication-for-wcf-httprest-services-authentication/)
- [Link 2](http://www.jayway.com/2012/01/05/secure-your-rest-based-wcf-service-with-wif-part-1/)
- [Link 3](http://forums.asp.net/t/1888818.aspx?Sample%20for%20Token%20based%20security%20implementation%20in%20REST%20service)